# Algorithm: Distance transform - any faster algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'm trying to solve distance transform problem (using Manhattan's distance). Basically, giving matrix with 0's and 1's, program must assign distances of every position to nearest 1. For example, for this one

```
0000
0100
0000
0000
```

distance transform matrix is

```
2123
1012
2123
3234
```

Possible solutions from my head are:

**Slowest ones (slowest because I have tried to implement them - they were lagging on very big matrices):**

1. Brute-force - for every 1 that program reads, change distances accordingly from beginning till end.
2. Breadth-first search from 0's - for every 0, program looks for nearest 1 inside out.
3. Same as 2 but starting from 1's mark every distance inside out.
4. **Much faster (read from other people's code)**

   Breadth-first search from 1's

   ```
   1. Assign all values in the distance matrix to -1 or very big value.
   2. While reading matrix, put all positions of 1's into queue.
   3. While queue is not empty
       a. Dequeue position - let it be x
       b. For each position around x (that has distance 1 from it)
           if position is valid (does not exceed matrix dimensions) then
               if distance is not initialized or is greater than (distance of x) + 1 then
                   I. distance = (distance of x) + 1
                   II. enqueue position into queue
   ```

I wanted to ask if there is faster solution to that problem. I tried to search algorithms for distance transform but most of them are dealing with Euclidean distances.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4) is a breadth first search starting with the `1`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The breadth first search would perform `Θ(n*m)` operations where `n` and `m` are the width and height of your matrix.

You need to output `Θ(n*m)` numbers, so you can't get any faster than that from a theoretical point of view.

I'm assuming you are not interested in going towards discussions involving cache and such optimizations.

---

Note that this solution works in more interesting cases. For example, imagine the same question, but there could be different "sources":

```
00000
01000
00000
00000
00010
```

Using BFS, you will get the following distance-to-closest-source in the same time complexity:

```
21234
10123
21223
32212
32101
```

However, with a single source, there is another solution that *might* have a slightly better performance in practice (even though the complexity is still the same).

Before, let's observe the following property.

**Property**: If source is at (a, b), then a point (x, y) has the following manhattan distance:

```
d(x, y) = abs(x - a) + abs(y - b)
```

This should be quite easy to prove. So another algorithm would be:

```
for r in rows
  for c in cols
    d(r, c) = abc(r - a) + abs(c - b)
```

which is very short and easy.

---

Unless you write and test it, there is no easy way of comparing the two algorithms. Assuming an efficient bounded queue implementation (with an array), you have the following major operations per cell:

- BFS: queue insertion/deletion, visit of each node 5 times (four times by neighbors, and one time out of the queue)
- Direct formula: two subtraction and two `if`s

It would really depend on the compiler and its optimizations as well as the specific CPU and memory architecture to say which would perform better.

That said, I'd advise for going with whichever seems simpler to you. Note however that with multiple sources, in the second solution you would need multiple passes on the array (or multiple distance calculations in one pass) and that would definitely have a worse performance than BFS for a large enough number of sources.

Comment: Wouldn't it be O(n^2*m^2), since there would be O(n*m) breadth first searches, each of which is O(n*m)?

Comment: @mbeckish- I don't believe so.  Once you have found the distance from a grid point to any 1, you never need to reprocess that square again.  You could therefore have a BFS starting from every single 1 at the same time and then never do any repeated work.

Comment: @templatetypedef - The trick is not reprocessing squares, and it probably depends upon the details of the implementation.  At the very least, the boundary nodes between regions will be checked multiple times (because you don't know when to stop expanding until you check a node that has already been processed and decide that it was closer to a different node).  Unless you can prove a constant upper bound for how many times a node can be checked, then you can't be sure it is O(n*m).

Comment: @mbeckish- Since each square has four neighbors, each square can be visited at most four times.  Or am I misinterpreting your concern?

Comment: @templatetypedef - I think you're right.  The only part that concerns me is `if distance is not initialized or is greater than (distance of x)`.  If it is possible for a square to be reached from a greater distance before it is reached from a closer distance, then I think the square can be visited many times.  However, I think the `is greater than (distance of x)` is unnecessary with the given algorithm, and each node should only be visited at most 4 times.

Comment: @mbeckish- I think that if you seed the BFS queue with all of the squares holding a 1 and then proceed from there, you will never run into this case.  The very first time that a node is reached in the queue must give the shortest path from *any* of the 1s to that particular 0.  Consequently, you'll never fill in the grid one time, then overwrite it on a second pass, then overwrite it on a third pass, etc.  But you're right - just iteratively running BFS is not going to give this guarantee.

Comment: @mbeckish, with a single source, that is true, but imagine a scenario with 2 sources right next to each other. When checking neighbors of one source, you will encounter the other source and that check makes sure you don't overwrite that source's distance to itself.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a queue or anything like that at all.  Notice that if (i,j) is at distance d from (k,l), one way to realise that distance is to go left or right |i-k| times and then up or down |j-l| times.

So, initialise your matrix with big numbers and stick a zero everywhere you have a `1` in your input.  Now do something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < sx-1; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < sy-1; j++) {
    dist[i+1][j] = min(dist[i+1][j], dist[i][j]+1);
    dist[i][j+1] = min(dist[i][j+1], dist[i][j]+1);
  }
  dist[i][sy-1] = min(dist[i][sy-1], dist[i][sy-2]+1);
}
for (j = 0; j < sy-1; j++) {
  dist[sx-1][j] = min(dist[sx-1][j], dist[sx-2][j]+1);
}
```

At this point, you've found all of the shortest paths that involve only going down or right.  If you do a similar thing for going up and left, `dist[i][j]` will give you the distance from (i, j) to the nearest `1` in your input matrix.